# Which expression is correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What I want to express is:

background:

When the CPU is processing data, multiple processes may use one CPU at the same time. In order to prevent the data of one process from being speculated by another person. Some people design the secure cache (the cache is a storage component inside the CPU. The data in the cache can be quickly retrieved by the CPU. However, it takes a long time for the CPU to retrieve data that is not in the cache.  Whenever the CPU uses data, it puts the data in the cache. This saves time when CPU use it again in the future. A process can measure the time it takes to access data A. If the time is short, then it can infer that someone else has accessed data A. If the access time is long, then it can infer that someone else has not accessed data A.

cache hit refers to the accessed data in the cache.
cache miss refers to the accessed data not in the cache.

> Getting all cache accesses to be hits is ideal, and this can be done
> using other on-chip storage [22], rather than a cache.
>
> Constant time using a cache can also be approached by “preloading” all the
> security-critical data into the cache, so that all accesses to them
> are cache hit

> One drastic approach is to disable the cache for security-critical
> accesses [8] so that all accesses to security-critical data miss in
> the cache.

The above three sentences are the ideas of three secure cache design.

I want to summarize them. The following two sentences are the summary I wrote.
May I ask which sentence can accurately express my meaning. Or both sentences are unreasonable?
Thanks.

> The previous secure cache design stores critical data (or
> directly prohibits access to critical data) by preloading or using
> other on-chip storage, so attackers can only observe cache hits (or
> misses) when reusing these data.
>
> The previous secure cache designs store critical data by
> preloading or using other on-chip storage
> (or directly prohibiting access to critical data)
> so that attackers can only observe cache
> hits (or misses) when reusing these data.

Comment: Both sentences are probably not what you want.  Are you really talking about a previous design? If so it should be “stored” not “stores”.  The “or” seems like it should be an “and”.  Why are attackers reusing the data?

Comment: Yes, `stored` is right if previous means designs that were used before the new one. And probably the sentence  needs to be - `prohibits direct access to critical data` .  Even otherwise, the term "directly prohibits" is confusing and can be better conveyed by just "prohibits" or "expressly prohibits"

Comment: thank you！  I added details.

Answer (score 0):

Both could potentially be correct. Note that I'm only responding from a grammatical point of view, so if there are technical errors they would be beyond me!

The first sentence gives the feeling that there has only been one previous secure design; and then goes on to explain how that design works. The second sentence gives the feeling that there have been multiple previous designs, but that they all work in the same way. Both sentences imply that there is now a new secure design, and I would assume you will explain how the new design works shortly.

Both sentences could also be read as a follow on to a previous discussion of one particular secure design (for the first sentence) or multiple particular secure designs (for the second sentence), in which case "previous" would mean previously in this text rather than previously in existence.

Comment: thank you！  I added details.